# I get incorrect values when printing Fibonacci numbers from the 93rd value upwards

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int fibonacciSum(int n);

int main(void) {
    int n = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d", fibonacciSum(n));
}

int fibonacciSum(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    uintmax_t previous = 0;
    uintmax_t current  = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
         printf("%ju and i %d\n", current, i);    
         uintmax_t tmp_previous = previous;
         previous = current;
         current = tmp_previous + current;
    }
    return current % 10;
}
```

This program calculates nth Fibonacci number and also the last digit of nth Fibonacci number. In my case, as I'm getting wrong values after the 92nd element, so the last digit is also coming out wrong. I'm using the [jdoodle](http://www.jdoodle.com/) online application to compile my C program.  What's going wrong?

Comment: 1. You need to say what values you're getting vs what you expect to get. 2. I don't know what the upper limit of `uintmax_t` is, but you might be overflowing the type. The 92nd Fib number would surely be huge.

Comment: http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/135157-why-does-fibonacci-sequence-script-stop-making-sense-92nd-iteration.html

Comment: When you get up to fib[93] or so, you're hitting the limits of what you can store in a 64-bit number, which is what I'm guessing `uintmax_t` is on your machine.  So you don't have a bug in your code, you've just gone as far as you can go on your machine, unless you want to start investigating the wonderful world of arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

Comment: fib[92] = 7540113804746346429 = 63 bits.
fib[93] = 12200160415121876738 = 64 bits.
fib[94] = 19740274219868223167 = 65 bits.

Comment: If you only need the last decimal digit, you don't need to overflow anything; simply keep the Fibonacci numbers modulo 10 during the loop. (If you think about it, (N1 + N2) % 10 == (N1 % 10 + N2 % 10) % 10).  If you need to be able to print the actual Nth Fibnacci number, you have to work harder.  A lot harder.

Comment: @JonathanLefflerCan you express how i can calculate Nth Fibonacci number in this situation without overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in the last digit of the Fibonacci numbers, do the computations modulo 10:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacciSum(int n);

int main(void) {
    int n = 0;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        printf("%d\n", fibonacciSum(n));
    }
    return 0;
}

int fibonacciSum(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    int previous = 0;
    int current  = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
         printf("fib(%d) % 10 = %d\n", i, current);
         int tmp_previous = previous;
         previous = current;
         current = (tmp_previous + current) % 10;
    }
    return current;
}
```

If you also want the complete numbers, you should use a multiprecision package (also called bignum) as Fibonacci numbers exceed 64 bits from the 93rd on.

You could write a simplistic one to handle addition of positive numbers only, stored as allocated strings of decimal digits. An interesting challenge for the next 24 hours, I shall post a simple program here then.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's an integer overflow in the case.

As [*Steve Summit* suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027984/i-get-incorrect-values-when-printing-fibonacci-numbers-from-the-93rd-value-upwar#comment79016260_46027984),

```
fib[93] = 12,200,160,415,121,876,738 = 64 bits
max_uint64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

So it's sure that `fib[94]` will cause an int overflow because it's larger than 2<sup>64</sup>.

You can use [arbitrary-precision arithmetics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) if you want a super big number.